# Can't Start Bitbucket on Vagrant with init.d Script

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, bitbucket, init.d

I have created an init.d script to start up my bitbucket server on reboot. Running on Ubuntu on Vagrant. I can run the script manually: sudo /etc/init.d/bitbucket/bitbucket.sh. But when I try to run sudo service bitbucket start, I get permission denied. Permissions on the file and directory are -rwxr-xr-x, owned by root.

Any thoughts? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a waste of time. I created a bitbucket directory in init.d, instead of just putting the script there. Works fine.